# Is there any kind of HLSL or HYDRA Pixel Shader languages for JAVA?

Tags: java, hlsl, pixel-shader

Is there any kind of HLSL or HYDRA Pixel Shader languages vorking in toch with for JAVA? So I have an image. I want to use some Pixel Shader language to modify it as I do in Flash with HYDRA or HLSL with C# (in  bouth cases I have precompiled shader). So how to use HYDRA or HLSL or any thing else for developing CROSSPLATFORM (win mac lin) JAVA stand alone APPLICATIONS?

I need some tutorials, please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GLSL](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/) and [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) in Java through [JOGL](https://jogl.dev.java.net/).

Comment: 1) will it work in browser
2) will it work on mobile devices
3) have you tried it or just googled it?

Comment: @Ole Jak
1.)When you use JOGL/OpenGL you get the sun dialog.press allow/trust.It should work on most browsers, but I've seen it fail on some PCs with Firefox/JRE.Didn't bother to look into it. 
2.) mobile devices usually support OpenGL ES which is a subset of OpenGL, so you need to check if the OpenGL features you plan to use on mobile are present in OpenGL ES.
3.)Here is my OpenGL assignment for the graphics course in term1: http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~ma802gp/abstract.It uses GLSL shaders. Got some Processing/java source code there.Shaders aren't uploaded, most of them are from GLSL Orange Book